# Can I use "to have" in this context?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing this sentence:

```
Goodbye to the most amazing teacher to have ever walked the Earth.
```

Is it correct to use "to have" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "to have" is part of the verb "to have walked". The sentence might be improved by changing the word order to keep the parts of the verb together:

> Goodbye to the most amazing teacher ever *to have walked* the Earth.

Comment: This is a style choice though, and they're both completely fine! I think the OP's sentence sounds a little less formal, if it matters.